# Why Wordpress Custom Role cannot access wp-admin?

Tags: wordpress, roles

I'm trying to create a role who could only accept one (custom) menu page of wp-admin.

Right now I'm trying to give access to wp-admin without seeing too much.

The role is defined like this :

```
function phs_comptable_add_custom_role() {
  if ( ! get_option( 'custom_roles_version' ) ) {
      $capabilities = array( 
      );
      add_role( 'comptable', 'Comptable', $capabilities );
      update_option( 'custom_roles_version', 1 );
  }
  $role_object = get_role( 'comptable' );
  // Ajouter une capacité
  $role_object->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );
  $role_object->add_cap( 'manage_options' );
  $role_object->remove_cap( 'customize' );
  $role_object->remove_cap( 'create_users' );
  $role_object->remove_cap( 'upload_files' );
  $role_object->add_cap( 'read' );
  $role_object->add_cap( 'view_site_health_checks' );
  $role_object->remove_cap( 'edit_theme_options' );
  $role_object = get_role( 'comptable' );
  var_dump($role_object);
}
add_action( 'init', 'phs_comptable_add_custom_role' );
```

But if I try to access wp-admin/ with a user having this role, he gets redirected to my-account/ (I have Woocommerce installed).

Question : how to give a minimal acccess to wp-admin and why doesn't it work right now ?

I tried changing various capabilities. I can only access wp-admin/ if I give the "edit_posts" capability for instance.

Comment: You need to add the following capabilities: 'read' => true, 'manage_categories' => true, and it should fix this issue hope this helps let me know if it worked.

Comment: @DevTurtle not working unfortunately :( I don't know how to debug it...

Comment: Should work try removing the role and adding it back with the new capabilities. You can remove it by commenting out your code in the hook function and add this line of code `remove_role( 'comptable' );`